# My F12 key isn't working, which is preventing me from being able to switch back to Windows

Tags: dual-boot, keyboard, shortcut-keys

After using a mechanical keyboard I can't seem to get my F10, F11, F12 keys to work. When I run `sudo evtest` and press F12 and Fn + F12 noting happens. How can I get these keys working again? Is there anyway to boot again without pressing F12?

Comment: Seems like you might have a faulty keyboard. Happily, replacing a keyboard is usually very easy and inexpensive.

Comment: You can reboot your machine simply enough by dropping to the command line and typing `sudo reboot` if that doesn't work try `sudo shutdown -r now`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What happened to grub? You can make your PC directly boot into windows by sending windows boot manager up in boot sequence in firmware setting which you can access by `F2`. I suppose `F2` works? Also please reply with @username...

Comment: @MarkD when I do this I am brought to the grub boot options. I am unsure how to get to windows from these options. What I am looking for is the Dell boot menu.

Comment: @SasukeUchiha F2 is working and it puts me in a terminal looking thing in grub. How can I then send the windows boot manager up the boot sequence from here?

Comment: @RyanMarr You should press `F2` before grub appears. Keep pressing it after you power up the PC until you get to firmware settings. But can't you boot into windows form grub?